# How to pause slideshow when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

How do I add a pause effect when I hover over an image in a jQuery slideshow?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {
    var showing = $('#slideshow .show');
    var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');
    var timer;
    showing.fadeOut(500, function () {
        next.fadeIn(200).addClass('show');
    }).removeClass('show');
    setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var hovering = false;               //default is not hovering
$("#slideshow").hover(function () { //*replace body with your element
    hovering = true;                //when hovered, hovering is true
}, function () {
    hovering = false;               //when un-hovered, hovering is false
    slideShow();                    //start the process again
});

function slideShow() {
    if(!hovering) {                 //if not hovering, proceed
        /* Your code here*/
        nextSlide();
        setTimeout(slideShow, 1000);
    }
}

function nextSlide(){
    var showing = $('#slideshow .show');
    var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');
    var timer;
    showing.fadeOut(500, function () {
        next.fadeIn(200).addClass('show');
    }).removeClass('show');
}
```

<kbd>***Demo:***</kbd> http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/mqEbZ/

Comment: OK, I got the image to appear, but it doesn't change pictures.

Comment: OK, I got it working again, but it seems the hover isnt working.

Comment: @GarrettJohnson - Did you replace `$("body")` with your target element?

Comment: Well which do I put in there? #slideshow or .show? this for my slide:

<div id="slideshow">
     <img class="show" src="../images/food/chicken_quesa.jpg">
     <img src="../images/food/beet_salad.jpg">
     <img src="../images/food/pasta_display.jpg">
    </div>

Comment: @GarrettJohnson - If you want the slideshow to pause when you hover `#slideshow`, then put `#slideshow` there.

Comment: @GarrettJohnson - It should work. Try the updated code I modified in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>[**`.delay()`**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)</kbd> that will help.

**Description:** Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two functions for that ... slideShow() and other one say pauseSlideshow()... now call the slideshow() on mouseout event and on mouseenter call pauseSlideShow()

your code should be something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.slider').mouseout( slideShow());
 $('.slider').mouseenter( pauseSlideShow());
 }); 
function slideShow() {
var showing = $('#slideshow .show');
var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');
var timer;
showing.fadeOut(500, function() { next.fadeIn(200).addClass('show'); }).removeClass('show');    
timeOut = setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);        
}

function PauseSlideShow() {
window.clearTimeout(timeOut);
}
```

TRY IT

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Derek's answer, an alternative to hover would be to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

See the working slideshow Jsfiddle: <kbd>**Demo:**</kbd> http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/6kDG7/

```
var hovering = false;
var slideshow = $("#slideshow");

slideshow.mouseenter(function() {
    hovering = true;
}).mouseleave(function() {
    hovering = false;
    slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {
    if (!hovering) {
        # Some browsers don't interpret "display:block" as being visible
        # If no images are deemed visible, choose the first...
        var currentImg = (slideshow.children("img:visible").length) ? slideshow.children("img:visible") : slideshow.children("img:first");
        var nextImg = (currentImg.next().length) ? currentImg.next() : slideshow.children("img:first");

        currentImg.fadeOut(500, function() {
            nextImg.fadeIn(500, function() {
                setTimeout(slideShow, 2000);
            });
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    slideShow();
});
```